# How can I exclude overlapping shapes to make a dashed line always visible against a solid overlap?

Tags: matplotlib, line, overlapping

I am trying to recreate the dashed line effect seen in the attached image using matplotlib.

[image]

I could not find any reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need Matplotlib v3.6.0 or higher, in which the (currently experimental) [`gapcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.6.0.html#striped-lines-experimental) option was added for dashed lines. You can see an example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/line_demo_dash_control.html), and I'll show an example below:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d = np.random.randn(30)
plt.plot(d, "g", lw=10)

# overplot a dashed line with gapcolor set to white
# (in your example image the linestyle is ":" rather than "--", so choose what you like)
plt.axhline(0, color="g", ls="--", gapcolor="white")
```

This gives:

[image]

If you don't have the latest Matplotlib version, or can't upgrade, you can get the effect by just plotting a white line and then a dashed line over the top (or vice versa), e.g.,

```py
plt.plot(d, "g", lw=10)

# plot a white line
plt.axhline(0, color="white")

# overplot a dashed green line
plt.axhline(0, color="g", ls="--"")
```

Comment: Love the idea of the white continuous line.

Comment: Thank You Matt, this is exactly what I was looking for, especially the white line trick. You Rock!